# Run java class from command line

Tags: java

I have java class file `main1.class`, which code in `main1.java` :

```
package m;

public class main1 {
     
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    System.out.println("*** start ***");    
    }
}
```

Trying to run

Attempt 1:

```
java -cp . main1
```

Got error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class main1
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: m/main1 (wrong name: main1)
```

Attept 2:

```
java -cp . m.main1
```

Got error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class m.main1
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: m.main1
```

Comment: Well, the name of the compiled binary file. The name of the source code file must end in `.java`.

Comment: afaik the classpath needs to be set to the folder that contains the `m` folder in this case. What folder are you running this command in?

Comment: You can run it with `javac main1.java` then `java main1`

Comment: @f1sh I was trying to run class from the same folder where it was located. Now it works!

Comment: When I enter the title of your question in the search box at the top of this Web page, I get over 3,000 [results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Run+java+class+from+command+line). Doesn't any one of them solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Java 11 and above, you can simply do
`java filename.java`

Till Java 11,
`javac filename.java`
`java filename`

Answer (score 0):

```
javac -d . main1.java
java -cp . m.main1
```

(Your source *not* in a package tree, but in the current directory)